# Check if All CheckBoxes Are Unchecked C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I would like to perform a task if all CheckBoxes in a StackPanel are unchecked. Currently I am doing something like this;

```
foreach (CheckBox c in _employees.Children)
{
    if (c.IsChecked == false)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

However of course this says that do something every time it comes across a `CheckBox` that is false. Is there a way I can say do something only if ALL the `CheckBoxes` are not checked, instead of evaluating them all individually?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can for example use [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if(_employees.Children.All(c=>!c.IsChecked)) {...}
```

**Edit**: you are using `UIElementCollection` which is not a generic collection. So you have to cast it first. The code will be

```
if(_employees.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().All(c=>c.IsChecked==false)) {...}
```

Or

```
if(_employees.Children.Cast<CheckBox>().All(c=>c.IsChecked==false)) {...}
```

The first approach will skip all the elements, which are not of `CheckBox` type, while the second will throw an exception if such elements are found

Comment: A negated version is `employees.Children.Any(c => c.Checked)`

Comment: Hmm I'm getting `UIElementCollection does not have a definition for All....`. _employees is a `StackPanel`...

Comment: add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file. It's an extension method

Comment: @OlegGolovkov Unless I'm being really short sighted still no luck after adding in the using...

Comment: Oh, I see why this is happening, check my updated answer

Comment: `Cannot convert bool? to bool` now! EDIT: This works; `if (_employees.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().All(c => Convert.ToBoolean(!c.IsChecked)))`

Comment: Or you can you your approach with `c.IsChecked == false`. I updated my answer with that